# Does xNeat Clipboard Manager work on Windows 10 not upgraded from Windows 7 (Or installed after Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, windows-10-v1511

I have installed xNeat on a system that ran Windows 7 and has been upgraded to Windows 10 and it works the same. On my new Windows 10 laptop and other laptop upgraded without installing xNeat before the upgrade, it does not work.

No icon appears in the system tray and the hot key doesn't open the menu. I tried compatibility settings for Windows 7 and when I ran the compatibility wizard it says it detected an incompatible program, but it's compatible on my other system.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you need assistance with xNeat you should either clarify what your question is or contact the support staff for xNeat to verify it specifically supports Windows 10.  Please understand, in order to help you, we have to know more then "it does not work".

Comment: When I say it "does not work" I mean no icon appears in the system tray and the keyboard shortcut doesn't open the menu. Good idea about contacting xNeat, but the link on their site to their forum seems to be down http://www.xneat.com/talk/

Comment: My question would be: Is anyone else having this issue, has anyone got xNeat to work (store clipboard data and let me pin entries) on Windows 10, why does it work on my computer upgraded from Windows 7 but not my other ones?

Comment: Do I have to install xNeat on Windows 7 and then upgrade to Windows 10 for it to work on Windows 10?

Comment: Asking if anyone else has this problem would not be question that would be on topic.  I assume the problem, due to the fact it actually running on a Windows 10 machine, is that your missing a required resource file.

Comment: If others have the same issue then I would know it's not just my laptop, but I already tried on another laptop. On this one I will try to revert to Windows 7 and install it, then upgrade again, but for my one that came with Windows 7 I'll have to use Ditto for now. I sent an email to the XNEAT.COM@domainsbyproxy.com adress listed in their whois.